# Change DataGridRowHeaderStyle (Background)?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background, styles

I would like to change the background of the RowHeader of a DataGrid in WPF. I made a style as static resource and want to add the style in C#. Below is the code, both in XAML/C#.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="GUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="newRowHeader" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dg = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid();
dg.RowHeaderStyle = (Style)FindResource("newRowHeader");
```

The error occurs at the last line of C# dg.RowHeaderStyle.... . The error:  'The invocation of the constructor on type 'GUI.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running this code? It is inside the constructor? If it is, then try to do it when the window is loaded:

```
public MainWindow(){
    //...
    Loaded+=(_,e)=>{
         System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dg = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid();
         dg.RowHeaderStyle = (Style)FindResource("newRowHeader");
    };
}
```

Maybe is that the window is not loaded yet. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Should use Resources["x:Key"].